# How to place page numbers in arbitrary position (e.g. REALLY in extreme right bottom corner)

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, geometry

Some questions and answers exist on how to place the page numbers (I quote) *"in the bottom (right) corner"*, but different people seem to have different (and multiple) definitions of such *corners*.

I am looking to place the page number, in the extreme bottom right corner, **understood as**: *as far to the right and as far to the bottom as possible (still perfectly visible)*.

That's just a little bit of a funny exercise, but of course I will not want the page numbers all the way there, for serious purposes.

For serious purposes, I am looking for an answer on how to place the page numbers in an arbitrary position (or applied, **almost** in the extreme right bottom corner). This will need to answer 2 components:

- How to shift the **vertical** component: this seems easy (in purposes known to me) using `\geometry{footskip=...pt}`.
- How to shift the **horizontal** component: this can be (somewhat) done with `\usepackage{geometry}` & `\hoffset=50pt`... BUT NOT QUITE -> It also shifts all of the contents on the page to the right. In particular, I am looking for a fix for this problem (unless you studious people would know a solution where you would like to avoid using `\hoffset` of course).

Here is a **M**inimal **W**orking (rather: not-working) **E**xample:

### MnotWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for showing some sample text
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\rfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\hoffset=50pt
\geometry{footskip=50pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

See how EVERYTHING is shifted 50pt to the right? Not ideally!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using package [`scrlayer-scrpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) instead `fancyhdr`. Than you can define a new layer and add this new layer to an existing page style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for showing some sample text

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles% clear all headers and footers
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  align=br,
  hoffset=\paperwidth,
  voffset=\paperheight+\dp\strutbox,
  contents={\vfill\hfill\pagemark}
]{pagenumberbottomright}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumberbottomright}
\begin{document}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

If would be also possible to load only [`scrlayer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer) and define a new layer page style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for showing some sample text

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  align=br,
  hoffset=\paperwidth,
  voffset=\paperheight+\dp\strutbox,
  contents={\vfill\hfill\pagemark}
]{pagenumberbottomright}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{pnbr}{pagenumberbottomright}
\pagestyle{pnbr}

\begin{document}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

---

**Update**

You can add a layer to different page styles. If the page number should be also on pages with style `plain` that is used by chapter and part pages you can use

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext} % only for showing some sample text

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles% clear all headers and footers
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  align=br,
  hoffset=\paperwidth,
  voffset=\paperheight+\dp\strutbox,
  contents={\vfill\hfill\pagemark}
]{pagenumberbottomright}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumberbottomright}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain}{pagenumberbottomright}

\begin{document}
\part{A part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If the page number should be on really every page including pages using page style `empty` than add the layer to page style `@everystyle@`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext} % only for showing some sample text

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles% clear all headers and footers
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  align=br,
  hoffset=\paperwidth,
  voffset=\paperheight+\dp\strutbox,
  contents={\vfill\hfill\pagemark}
]{pagenumberbottomright}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{pagenumberbottomright}

\begin{document}
\part{A part}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

Note that if you only load `scrlayer` (instead `scrlayer-scrpage`) you have to declare `plain` as a layer page style.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext} % only for showing some sample text

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  align=br,
  hoffset=\paperwidth,
  voffset=\paperheight+\dp\strutbox,
  contents={\vfill\hfill\pagemark}
]{pagenumberbottomright}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{pnbr}{pagenumberbottomright}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{plain}{pagenumberbottomright}
\pagestyle{pnbr}

%\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{pagenumberbottomright}

\begin{document}
\part{A part}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to make it work **on all pages** (including pages where `\part{...}`s or `\chapter{...}`s start, while in `\documentclass{report}` please?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

*TikZ* package can be used to place page numbers at arbitrary positions. You will also need the `background` package to set a new background. Her is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,background}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for showing some sample text

\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\pagestyle{fancy}

\backgroundsetup{%
contents={%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,opacity=100]
    \node[text=black] at ([shift={(-1em,1em)}]current page.south east){\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  },
  scale=1,
  angle=0
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Which gives this:

[image]

Comment: I can not retrieve any visible footnote upon compilation. It's probably a small glitch, would you know what's causing the issue?